# swift4: Firebase Notification not working when sending notification from server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

I'm using Swift4: 
I want to create firebase push notification, i'd follow steps as this video [firebase push notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCd_7LuFdvw)
and this is the app delegate code:

```
import UIKit
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import FBSDKLoginKit
import TwitterKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    print("user tooooken: ", Common.getUserToken())
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
        if(error == nil) {
            print("successful authentication")
        }
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshToken(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)


    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:255/255.0, green:51/255.0, blue:255/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]

    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"xxxxxxxxxxx", consumerSecret:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBHandler()
}

///// Twitter authentication //////
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }
    return true
}

@objc func refreshToken(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refreshToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    print(refreshToken)

    FBHandler()
}

func FBHandler() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

}
```

when I push notification from firebase server it delivered successfully to the device, but when the php server sent push notification it doesn't work, is i forget any step ?

Comment: Check with the breakpoint, Is your Appdelegate class calling.

Comment: Have you added firebase server key in the PHP file? that is required to send push notification from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these:

1. you have sent firebase FCM token of your device to your server.
2. If your server sent you a data notification then it's data object
   should be in 'notification' key.
3. Also when user logout from device you should have to delete user's FCM 
   token from server.